# Java program started using windows task scheduler but not creating log files in batch file folder

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, scheduler

I have started java program (with batch file script) using Windows task scheduler. and in my log4.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file1
log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.file1.File=personal-info.log 
log4j.appender.file1.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.file1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] [%F:%L] : %m%n
log4j.logger.com.personal=INFO,  file1
log4j.additivity.com.personal=false
log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false
log4j.additivity.org.jboss=false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
log4j.additivity.org.dozer=false
```

When I start my batch file from command line, this file gets created in same folder of batch file, but when I start it from windows task scheduler, it doesn't create log files either in batch file folder or anywhere else in machine.

One more thing, this task was started by other user, has anyone else has this issue before and solution is to provide physical path of folder in log4.properties?

Answer (score 2):

You will encounter path and classpath issue with Task Scheduler.
The user set to execute the scheduled task probably has a different PATH and classpath definition.
The user set to execute the scheduled task has user privilege that could impact your batch execution.
Your batch file has to set everything in order to run as you expect.

Hope this could help.

regards,
Yann

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when the .bat file is executed by the Task Scheduler to start my small Java application. The log4j logfiles are simply not being created. But when I run the batch file from the command line everything works fine. As rishman suggested, there has to be something with PATH/classpath.

However you can save to file the logs generated by your batch file:

[image]

This will create a .log file in the location where the batch file is.